# JS - onchange func in webpack does not appear

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```
function checkEvent(elem)
{
 if (elem.checked)
 {
    alert("Im Checked");
 }
 else
 {
    alert("Im not checked");
 }
}
<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkEvent(this);"/>
```

I'm dynamically adding this input and it works fine. But when I transpile the app.js with babel it doesn't work.

```
console error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: checkEvent is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onchange
```

If someone could explain this error, the help would be greatly appreciated.